# Update content of all span element with their own text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="resultperpage">
    <span><a>12</a></span>
    <span><a>24</a></span>
    <span><a>48</a></span>
    <span><a>98</a></span>
</div>


$('#resultperpage span').click(function() {
    $('#resultperpage span').html($(?).html() + 'A'));
});

<div id="resultperpage">
    <span><a>12A</a></span>
    <span><a>24A</a></span>
    <span><a>48A</a></span>
    <span><a>98A</a></span>
</div>
```

Please help me replace question mark in jQuery function so that output is text + 'A'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the callback function for `html()` instead to replace all of them

```
$('#resultperpage span').click(function() {
    $('#resultperpage span').html(function(_, html) {
        return html + 'A';
    });
});
```

or to replace just the clicked one

```
$('#resultperpage span').click(function() {
    $(this).html(function(_, html) {
        return html + 'A';
    });
});
```

Comment: What I want is that when a user clicks on any span element, all span element text should change to old text + 'A'. How is that possible?

Comment: @ars, read the documentation for `html()` with function argument. It will loop all elements in collection

Answer (score 1):

**JQuery**

```
$("#resultperpage span a").each(function(){
    var txt= $(this).text();
    $(this).text(txt+"A");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/px4wgz0r/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **[each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** function:

```
$('#resultperpage span').click(function() {
    if($(this).html().substr($(this).html().length-1)!='A'){
        $('#resultperpage span').each(function(){
            $(this).html($(this).html() + 'A');
        });
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ny1rcyk6/)**